# CakePHP not finding anything if HABTM model does not have any associated models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having some trouble with CakePHP 3.4.  I have a HABTM model for users and comments.  In the users model, I need to be able to find all comments (not just those from the current user).  In UsersController I do `$this->Users->Comments->find('all');` and it works fine for users who have commented, but it returns no comments if the user has never commented.  This happens even though I am using find all and even though there are other comments in the database.

I also tried `$this->loadModel('Comments'); $this->Comments->find ('all');` with the same results.

Any idea how I can get this to work for users with no comments?

Thank you!

Comment: Share your model code.

Comment: Also, share the actual code you're using in your controller.

Comment: Nevermind...  I just noticed that there is an if (!empty($users->comments)) in the view that was causing my data not to display...  #nooberrors

Comment: For those who face this problem, it could have to do with the `joinType` settings of the association inside the model... just fyi